# How to activate specific PHP includes

Tags: php

I have many PHP includes on my webpage; I don't want them active until a button is clicked or someone hits enter.

AND then I would like to call the specific DIV ID [php include] and not all of them on the page.

I have an input field that the user would enter a zip code, then hit the go button or enter key, after that happens; I would like the script to activate the php include for that div ID.

For example: I have a - div id="zip60538" - that has a php include - [include myfile.php]

which I don't want activated on page load, I only want the DIV ID php include activated after the go button or enter is hit.

There will be a 100 div id's with PHP includes so I would like to be specific and only fire the matching DIV ID PHP Include and not all of them on the page. Each DIV is setup as zip(then the actual zip code) so zip60538 is the div ID and the user would enter 60538 in the input field.

What I was thinking is: 
1. look at input box 
2. if zip+(input box values) matches 
3. then activate my.php include, in div id zip60538

is that possible?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var zipCodes   =[60538,60504,75001,76008,75002,75013,76009,76225,75409,76226,76001,76002,76006,76010,
76011,76012,76013,76014,76015,76016,76017,76018,76227,76020,75413,75180,75101,76021,
76022,75414,76126,75424,75418,76023,76028,75135,75006,75007,75010,76127,75104,75423,
75009,75105,76031,75211,76034,76233,75121,75019,75114,76035,76036,];
$("#buttontest").click(function(){
 var zipIndex = zipCodes.indexOf(parseInt($("#full_day").val()));
 $("#zipMessage > div").hide("fast");
 var zipId = zipIndex > -1 ? zipCodes[zipIndex] : "Error";
$("#zip"+zipId).show("fast");
});

$("#full_day").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which === 13){
     $("#buttontest").click();
}
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7SPGh/35

Comment: include code please...

Comment: I don't believe this is possible as PHP's work is done on page generation. So after the page is presented to the user it is to late to do anything.

Comment: That's not possible. What you can do is use JQuery and load a page in a div when a button is clicked though.

Comment: what is the content of your includes?

Comment: On client side you can only switch visibility of a loaded element. If you want the dynamic behavior you mention, you will likely have to resort to AJAX calls and inject content into the DOM.

Comment: The problem is the IFRAME SRC loads all of the maps at once and when I have a 100 of them it gets to big. I wanted to do something like a php include of the first part of the SRC i.e. src="http://maps.google.com/maps? and only call that after the go button or enter is hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP runs on the server and by the time the browser loads your web page, PHP has "already done its thing" and can no longer hold an open conversation with the browser.

That being said, your best option here is to use AJAX. And in keeping things as simple as possible, I recommend using [jQuery's .ajax() method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

This way, once a user takes an action, you can handle that event using JavaScript, call something from the PHP on the server, and return it back to the browser for use (essentially creating an open conversation between the browser and the server).

An example would look like this:

```
$("#some_button").on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'some_php_script.php',
        data: {foo : "bar"}
    })
    .done(function(results) {
        // check to see if results is actually html
        // going to assume it is for the sake of example
         $("#zip60538").html(results);
    });
});
```

You mentioned you have `hundreds of separate includes`, so creating a basic function that takes arguments and abstracts this functionality would be best for your particular case. AJAX is the way to go. Good luck!